# Is there a compiler define to see if a unit is used by a library?

Tags: delphi, dll

I have a unit with record definitions and some helper routines.

Because there are strings to share the first uses must look like:

```
unit SharedStuff;

interface

uses
  ShareMem,....
```

I want to only use the `ShareMem` if the unit is used in the context of a dll.

Is there a `{$ifdef ...}` that allows me to see if the unit is used by a libary or an executable?

```
uses
  {$ifdef InLibrary}  <<--?
  ShareMem,
  {$else}
  FastMM,
  {$ifend}
```

Comment: There's no such conditional, as explained at the dupe Q. What you'll need to do is define conditionals in the project files. I wonder why the `uses` are not in the .dpr file. If you don't put them there, then it's too late.

Comment: Indeed, the `.dpr` file is where I always put that kind of thing, including `ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown:= True;` and units that need to be initialized before anything else.